# Can you delete the I386 Folder on Win Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

Can I remove this?  I don't know if it's something like where in XP you'd have to copy the I386 folder down for certain installs...is it?

I want to rid it to free up hard disk space.

Comment: So it looks like it's basically like I said...you need it to install stuff at times.  Screw it, I'm blowing it away.  It's on a VM that's going to be going away anyway so I really do not need it.  This VM is slow as hell and I need to free up disk space.  I only have 2gb left.

Comment: Why not just do something to expand your virtual disk instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably better to keep it around, but generally speaking its ok to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove i386 directory with the caveat that if you need to install new services you need the windows cd handy, or if corrupt files or if you install new hardware.
it's not critical to the operation of windows itself.